# What is the behavior when all the lines of the range of a diagnostic is deleted?

Tags: neovim

When I setup a diagnostic using `vim.diagnostic.set()` api and then later delete the range of the lines which the diagnostic is set, shouldn't that diagnostic entry be automatically removed or is it the responsibility of the user to remove it?

Since I could see that when editing within the range of the diagnostic entry, it will automatically update range. Therefore, I'd prefer it to automatically remove itself when all the rows of the range are removed rather than user having to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I wonder if your question is a bug report or a change request for Neovim. In such case maybe should it be placed in Neovim GitHub site.

Comment: While this isn't a substitute for a definitive answer, I suggest reading the source or trying it out and seeing what happens